# Using DOM directly in Vue unit test when no alternative

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-jest

How do I correct my unit test to correctly test for the below?

Method:

```
close(event) {
  const element = !!event?.target?.closest('#target')

  if (!element) {
    this.isVisible = false
  }
},
```

Jest test:

```
  it('should hide visibility if element is false', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(AccountLogin, { mocks })
    wrapper.vm.close()

    expect(wrapper.vm.$data.isVisible).toBe(false)
  })
```

Comment: One of many reasons to not use dom directly in vue is that it's less straightforward to test

Comment: I do understand but I have to target a third party script and this is the only way. Is it possible to test?

Comment: The question doesn't specify the framework you use. It looks like Jest but this needs to be explicitly stated because it's the thing you ask about. You could add an element to Jest's fake dom by regular browser API methods, remove it in afterEach. But here you need to just provide mocked `event` object that behaves the way `event?.target?.closest('#target')` is expected to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `change()` event is fired on the root element of your component, this should work:

```
jest.spyOn(wrapper, 'closest')
    .mockImplementationOnce(() => true)

wrapper.vm.close()
expect(wrapper.vm.$data.isVisible).toBe(false)
```

If the event is triggered on a child of root component element, you'll need to pass that child to `spyOn`, so you mock that child's `closest`, instead of the `wrapper`s. e.g:

```js
jest.spyOn(wrapper.find('input'), 'closest')
    .mockImplementationOnce(() => true)
// ...
```

Why you need to find the exact element: this is `jsdom`: it's not actual DOM. Events don't bubble.

---

What the above does: it hijacks `.closest()` method of  `event.target`'s element so it returns `true`.
Which, in your case, will cause

```
!!event?.target?.closest('#target')
```

to return `true`, so `this.isVisible = true` will be executed.

If you want to test that it's not executed when `#target` is not found, write a second test, with a `.closest()` mock returning `false` and test that `isVisible` has not been set from `false` to `true` upon invoking `.close()`. Doing more than that would be testing that HTML works as expected.
I recommended you trust that it does.